# Retrieving several XML files from different web services

Tags: android, xml, web-services

I need to retrieve large number of XML files, each from a different web service. These are connected, all of the data will eventually be used for one object. I was thinking of having one class for each web service, each with an individual `AsyncTask` to retrieve the data, then sending requests in sequence, so that when one retrieves data I start the next until they have all completed.

What I'd like to know is if there is a better method of doing this, as it stands it all feels a bit inefficient. I have no control over these web services, I cannot modify or combine them, I can only change the way the app retrieves the information.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to send the requests one-at-a-time.  AsyncTasks come from a thread pool managed by the Android system.  If the web service calls do not have dependencies on each other, you should be able to send several at the same time.

And of course if you use one class per web service call, you should attempt to factor out the common logic into base classes.  For example, if several of the web services are REST, you might want to consider a RESTWebService base class that handles all common HTTP/REST concerns.

Also consider using 3rd-party libraries for common tasks.  Some that may apply in your case would be Apache HTTPComponents (for pure HTTP calls), RESTlet (for rest web services), KSoap (if you have any SOAP services).